# Clustering via Pattern Formation

Tags: sequences-and-series, clustering

I have a range of numbers for instance:
$$x = (-2,0,3,10,11,15,100,111,112,113).$$

How do I multiply this set of values ($x$) to yield the following ranges?
\begin{align*}
x_1 &= (-2,0,3),\\
x_2 &= (10,11,15),\\
x_3 &= (100,111,112,113).
\end{align*}
*As a computer scientist, I would find the absolute difference between each value then sort it in a list. This is not very optimal.*

I was wondering if there exists mathematical functions that allow me to sort the numbers into clusters? Please help!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thanks Jose, I didn't understand how to start a MathJax block in my code, sorry.

Comment: @AhmadM. Such functions really depend on the array itself since for each specific array, there's an ad hoc function for clustering. To find a generic function, more properties of the values in the array are needed beforehand.

Comment: Sounds like you want a [cluster analysis algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis). Your idea about taking differences between adjacent values is similar to [hierarchical clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering).

Comment: @AlexFrancisco: This is what I meant, the differences between individual values and then groupwise difference would result in a pattern. We can then sort these differences and use them as indexes to sort the numbers as well. Does there exist a mathematical function to do this ? Like how the exponential function makes the small values smaller and large values larger.

Comment: @Rahul: Yes, it seems I need an divisive hierarchical clustering algorithm for this, there exists the DIANA (DIvisive ANAlysis Clustering) algorithm, but I am looking for mathematical functions to achieve the same result.